# How can i find the number of 9s in an integer

Tags: c#

I have the following method which should found the total number of 9 in an integer, the method is used to retrieve the employees' contract type based on the number of 9. i tried the below class:-

```
public class EmployeeCreditCards
{
    public uint CardNumber(uint i)
    {
        byte[] toByte = BitConverter.GetBytes(i);

        uint number = 0;
        for (int n = 0; n < toByte.Length; n++)
        {
            if (toByte[i] == 9)
            {
                number = number + 1;
            }
        }
        return number;
    }
}
```

In which i am trying to find how many 9 are in the passed integer, but the above method will always return zero. Any idea what is going wrong?

Comment: Do you want to count the number of occurences of the digit 9 ? 123498949 to return 3 ?

Comment: Wow, storing a CreditCard number as an `uint`? You could just `Convert.ToString` and then check it (much easier, IMHO).

Comment: yes the number of 9 ... for example in 19199 it should return 3.

Comment: @johnG You should accept SydnerCoder's answer!

Comment: but why my approahc is not working ,, i do not want to use LINQ..

Comment: @johnG Your approach isn't working because you compare each byte, rather than each digit, in the number.  See Desolator's solution which uses your approach, but in a working manor.

Comment: @johnG just saying "the number of nines" is ambiguous - in what base do you want to work? Going by your example, probably base 10, and usually I would assume this except in this case you actually *were* counting (or at least attempting to) the number of 9's, only in base 256.

Comment: Did you copy-paste this code or type it in here?  `toByte[i]` seems like it should raise an exception for any `i > 3`.

Comment: @Servy:  When I run this code _as is_ with 4, it throws an exception.

Comment: @AustinSalonen You are correct, I assumed that `i` was the loop variable.  I hate it when people do the opposite.

Comment: @johnG "I do not want to use LINQ" - on its face, this is an inane restriction. Do you have a reason why?

Comment: @Servy but this what i need the number of 9 bits in a number

Comment: @johnG number of 9 bits? Usually the comments clarify the question, but this time they make it weirder..

Answer (score 23):

You can do this simple with a little linq:

```
public int GetAmountOfNine(int i)
{
    return i.ToString().Count(c => c.Equals('9'));
}
```

But do add `using System.Linq;` to the cs file.

Your answer isn't working because you are converting to bytes, converting the number to bytes does not generate a byte for each digit <sub>(via [@Servy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1159478/servy))</sub>. Therefor if you would write every byte in your array to console/debug you wouldn't see your number back.

**Example:**

```
int number = 1337;
byte[] bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(number);

foreach (var b in bytes)
{
    Console.Write(b); 
}
```

**Console:**

> 57500

You can however convert the int to a string and then check for every character in the string if it is a nine;

```
public int GetAmountOfNineWithOutLinq(int i)
{
    var iStr = i.ToString();
    var numberOfNines = 0;
    foreach(var c in iStr)
    {
        if(c == '9') numberOfNines++;
    }
    return numberOfNines;
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't you need `ToCharArray()` first? Or am i missing an extension for `.Select`?

Comment: I think you meant `Where` instead of `Select`, but more to the point, you can use `.Count(c => c.Equals('9'))` equivalently.

Comment: @BradChristie `string` implements `IEnumerable<char>`.

Comment: @PlatinumAzure: Wow, I never knew that. (of course never thought to iterate over a string either. :shrug:)

Comment: @PlatinumAzure implemented it, thx for that reminder. Knew it, just took the short round.

Comment: This answer would be much more useful if you explained to the OP _why_ his initial attempt does not work.

Comment: You don't *have* to convert the number to a string, and the reason that you gave for why it doesn't work when converting it to bytes is incorrect.  In your example foo and bar would actually be equal.  The problem is that converting to bytes doesn't give each (base ten) digit as a single byte.

Comment: @driis I explained why his version didn't work. Does it have you approval now? :P

Comment: @SynerCoder, certainly, and I had already +1'ed before making that comment :-)

Comment: @driis just making sure it had your approval, and thx for the +1, my best answer ever (according to SO), I personally think http://stackoverflow.com/a/10332609/637425 this answer is my best. :P

Comment: @SynerCoder Your explanation is now no longer *wrong*, but it doesn't really make much sense either.  `" if you convert to bytes your complete number is converted to bytes and not individual number each"`.  I assume you meant to say something along the lines of, "converting the number to bytes does *not* generate a byte for each digit" which is clearly his primary problem.

Comment: @Servy I did meant that indeed, mind if I edit your line into my answer?

Comment: @SynerCoder I intended for you to.

Comment: @SynerCoder The second method will cause a compilation error :) Did you confuse C# `foreach` with Java enhanced `for` loop?

Comment: @Desolator nope, but I tested it in the C# interactive Window. That is where I got the output from.

Comment: @Desolator but il test and edit it when I am no longer on my phone

Comment: @SynerCoder `for(var c in str)` is working without errors? How?

Comment: @Desolator fixed, i was looking at my 2nd code block instead of ny third, thx 4 mentioning

Answer (score 20):

A classic solution is as follows: (Probably this is **the fastest algorithm** to find solution, it takes only **O(log n)** time.)

```
private int count9(int n)
{
     int ret = 0;
     if (n < 0)
        n = -n;
     while (n > 0)
     {
         if (n % 10 == 9) ++ret;
         n /= 10; // divide the number by 10 (delete the most right digit)
     }
     return ret;
}
```

**How does that work?**
Consider an example, n = 9943

now *ret* = 0.

n % 10 = 3, which != 9

n = n / 10 = 994

n % 10 = 4 != 9

n = 99

n % 10 = 9, so ret = 1

n = 9

n % 10 = 9, so ret = 2

n = 0

Comment: @johnG if you type `n = n / 10;` you can short it to `n /= 10;`

Comment: @johnG same with `+=`, `%=`, `*=`, `-=` from the top of my head

Comment: @SynerCoder and `<<=`, `>>=`, `|=`, `&=` and `^=`, from the top of my head

Comment: @johnG I added explaination for that

Comment: Why not just set n positive on the first line? `n = Math.abs(n)` or whatever is necessary.

Comment: @Desolator it would seem to me that `n /= 10;` would delete the most right digit, not the most left one.

Comment: @SynerCoder Oh... yes :) :) How did I write that? :)

Comment: Everybody makes mistakes, I first wrote Select instead of Where. Which could get reduced by placing the lambda in the Count function. 3 Revisions already down the road. :P

Comment: I like how this accidentally works for `int.MinValue`, which stays negative when negated, but has zero nines in it in base10 anyway so it still works out.

Comment: This solution is not `O(log(n))`, it is `O(n)`.  This is a string searching problem and `n` represents the number of characters in the string, not the size of the initial integer.  `O(n)` because there are four `%` operations on a string of length four.

Comment: @eternalmatt I mean if `n = 1234`, for example, it would take only 4 iterations (which is `floor(log10(n))`). I mean `O(log n)` in terms of `n` itself as a number, not a string. The other solutions using ToString() are of the same complexity.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
int numberOfNines = number.ToString().Where(c => c == '9').Count();
```

Since a string implements `IEnumerable<char>`, you can apply LINQ directly to the string without converting it to an enumeration of chars first.

---

**UPDATE**

Converting the `uint` to a byte array won't work the expected way, since the `uint` does not store the decimal digits of your number directly. The number is stored as a binary number that streches over four bytes. A `unit` has always four bytes, even if your number has 9 decimal digits.

You can convert the number to a string in order to get its decimal representation.

Comment: I redacted my comment, but for the record it wasn't me who down-voted.

Comment: Your explanation is wrong.  First off, you don't *need* to convert it to a string, see Desolator's answer.  Second, it has nothing to do with a byte being a binary number, or `unit` having a binary representation.  Converting the int to bytes will give you (in effect) a four digit base 256 number that is equal to the integer.  The problem was that he needs to get each base *10* digit out.  That's certainly *possible*, he just didn't do it right.

Comment: @Servy: I said "must convert .. in order to get its decimal representation". The OP expected a byte array, each byte containing the value of one decimal digit. `unit` has an internal binary representation that stretches over the four bytes.

Comment: "The OP expected a byte array, each byte containing the value of one decimal digit" That seems apparent, and indeed is a false assumption.  All you really need to say is that much.  Your assumption that you need to convert it to a string to get each decimal digit is incorrect though.

Comment: @Servy: The algorithmic approach of Desolator gets the decimal digits one by (which is fine) one without getting the decimal representation of the number in a closed form. Changed my "must" to a "can".

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes That's my point exactly.  You *can* get the decimal digits by converting it to a string, but that's not the *only* way.